# How to fix error: implicit declaration of function ‘setup_timer’

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, compilation, linux-kernel, include

Trying to compile Linux core module for usb-audio card Line6 UX2.
Got code from repo and trying to make. Repo have no ./configure

Make produce error:

```bash
line6linux-code-r1108/driver/trunk/driver.c:169:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘setup_timer’; did you mean ‘del_timer’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  setup_timer(timer, function, data);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~
  del_timer
```

C function setup_timer() declare in the linux linux-headers package. Currently is linux-headers-4.18.0-16
Of course it's installed in the default place /usr/src/

Code which produces error (driver.c):

```c
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/timer.h>
#include <linux/export.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/usb.h>

#include <sound/core.h>
#include <sound/initval.h>

#include "capture.h"
#include "driver.h"
#include "midi.h"
#include "playback.h"

... some code here

/*
    Setup and start timer.
*/
void line6_start_timer(struct timer_list *timer, unsigned long msecs,
               void (*function)(unsigned long), unsigned long data)
{
    setup_timer(timer, function, data); // <-- string 169
    mod_timer(timer, jiffies + msecs_to_jiffies(msecs));
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(line6_start_timer);
```

So apparently compiler can't find Linux headers. How can I fix it?

Also based on the INSTALL file, it follows that the driver was written for the kernel version linux-headers-2.6.x and now it's 4.18.0-16.

And more from INSTALL: For other distributions, please consult the documentation to find out which package you have to install.

Everything is lost?

OS Ubuntu 18.10
Linux 4.18.0-16-generic #17-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 8 00:06:57 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Are you sure you really need to build this driver? I think Ubuntu includes a pre-built driver in its linux-module-extra packages which are installed as a dependency of the "generic" kernels. The kernel config option is CONFIG_SND_USB_TONEPORT and the module is called "snd-usb-toneport.ko".

Comment: @Alex did you manage to compile this driver? If yes, please share the changed code. I'm trying to use UX1 with my guitar on linux mint

Comment: @IanAbbott there is problems with line6 audio interface. Output sound is fine, but when I plug in the guitar  - there is no any signal. Same situation was in windows untill I install drivers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In newer version of Linux kernel, `setup_timer` function is known as `timer_setup`.

Note, that type of the callback function has been changed in the resent versions. Now that callback accepts pointer to `timer_list` structure itself.

See more in this LWN article: https://lwn.net/Articles/735887/.

Comment: As an aside, `timer_setup` was added in kernel 4.14 and `setup_timer` was removed in kernel 4.15.